# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, arrays

Need help with this..i was trying to convert Object type array to String type array by the below code:

```
Object matNodes[] = null;
Iterable<Vertex> vertex = tb.printNodes();
Iterator itr = vertex.iterator();
if(vertex.iterator().hasNext()){
    matNodes = IteratorUtils.toArray(itr);
}
String[] stringArray = Arrays.asList(matNodes).toArray(new String[matNodes.length]);
```

But getting below exception..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone please guide me to resolve this.

Comment: does any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.copyOf`:-

```
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(matNodes, matNodes.length, String[].class);
```

Sample Ex:-

```
Object matNodes[] = new Object[3];
    matNodes[0] = "abc";
    matNodes[2] = "fde";
    matNodes[1] = "qw";
    String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(matNodes, matNodes.length, String[].class);
```

Comment: I tired this code.. but getting same exception.

Comment: It means your object array (matNodes) does not contain Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are getting the `ArrayStoreException` because you are trying to convert an `Iterator` to an `array` in this line:

```
if(vertex.iterator().hasNext()){
    matNodes = IteratorUtils.toArray(itr); //itr here is an iterator
}
```

In other words you are trying to put an `iterator` in an array of Strings.

You should use `itr.next()` to get the iterated object and put it in the array, change your code like this:

```
if(vertex.iterator().hasNext()){
   matNodes = IteratorUtils.toArray(itr.next()); //Here you get the iterated object
}
```